# Django-ratings error: "rating value must be a Rating instance, not '100"?

Tags: python, django, django-ratings

Im trying to order a set of model objects by rating with Django-ratings app. I've built a order_by function in my view which works fine but not when i comes to the rating field where im getting this error: **"rating value must be a Rating instance, not '100"**. Any ideas whats wrong with this / or what the error means?

Thank you!

Template:

```
<a href="/mylist/?order_by=rating">Order by Rating</a>
```

View:

```
def Mylist(request):    
    order_by = request.GET.get('order_by', 'created_date')  
    mylist = Mymodel.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by(order_by)

    if order_by == "rating":
        qs = Mymodel.objects.filter(user=request.user).extra(select={
        'rating': '((100/%s*rating_score/(rating_votes+%s))+100)/2' % (Mymodel.rating.range, Mymodel.rating.weight)
        })
        mylist = qs.order_by('-rating')

    context = {'mylist ': mylist }
    return render_to_response('mylist.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Model:

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=140, blank=True)
   rating = RatingField(range=5)
```

Comment: show us Mymodel definition

Comment: Please add the definition of `Mymodel` and full stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Ok. Mymodel is just a regular class with some different fields where on field is a "ratingfield" called 'rating'.

Answer (score 1):

Try to rename extra attribute 'rating'

```
queryset = queryset.extra(select={
    'myrating': '((100/%s*rating_score/(rating_votes+%s))+100)/2' % (Mymodel.rating.range, Mymodel.rating.weight)
})
queryset = queryset.order_by('-myrating')
```

Comment: This worked for me! The documentation needs to be edited for django-ratings @dcrammer